# How to add a TabView beneath AppBar without shadow

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout

In my application I have an issue where I want to have high level navigational control from a navigation drawer, and page level control within a TabLayout within a fragment. This however causes issues with the shadow rendering from the AppBar onto the fragment.

[image: This is the look I want]

[image: This is the look I have]

Here's the basics of what my layouts and code does.  At the root I have this simple layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainAppActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When my navigation drawer is selected I inflate the fragment into "content_main"

```
    this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(tag)
            .replace(R.id.content_main_layout, fragment, tag)
            .commit();
```

The fragment being put into **content_main** contains a layout with my TabView and a view pager:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_github_issues"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/github_issues_tab_layout"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/github_issues_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What's the a good best practice to fix the issue?  Is including TabLayout to live within the top level AppBar and just disabling the view based on the page an acceptable implementation?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the view hierarchy to something like this:

```
FrameLayout
  -CoordinatorLayout -> content
  -Toolbar
```

Fix `Toolbar` elevation to be exact with the `AppBarLayout`, too get rid of the shadow but keep the z-order of the `Toolbar`:

```
int appBarLayoutElevation = ViewCompat.getElevation(mAppBarLayout);
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setElevation(appBarLayout);
```

Similar example I have worked in [my blog post](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/the-power-of-appbarlayout-offset-ecbf8eaa6b5f#.m7dwcxq7h).